# Turn bluetooth on and wait for intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I have an Android App that requires some Bluetooth settings; see below:

```
if (!Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
while (!Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
if (Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
    Intent discoverableIntent = new
        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
}
while (Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
} // do some stuff with bluetooth
```

This seems like a hack to me, and it only works if the user selects "yes". I'm pretty sure I need to be waiting on a result from these intents. How is that done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and implement [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method which will be called when user returns from the called activity.

For the check whether Bluetooth is enabled change code to:

```
if (!Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
} else {
    progressToNextCheck();
}
```

Then in the `progressNextCheck()` implement your check for the Bluetooth discoverability in a similar manner.

```
private void progressToNextCheck(){
    if (Constants.mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
        startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT);
    } else {
        goToTheTask();
    }
}
```

And your `onActivityResult()` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             progressToNextCheck();
         }
     } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             goToTheTask();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, so you suggest that rather than working directly with 'discoverability' inside the `onActivityResult` callback that instead you should call a state machine function to do the next task.  Neat solution!